# INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, trigger, identity, bulk-insert

Consider this a follow-up to [BULK INSERT: Trials and Tribulations](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154185/bulk-insert-trials-and-tribulations)

I have the following `VIEW` defined and would like to insert into the multiple underlying tables when sending a `BULK INSERT` from a CSV.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.StagingViewB as 
  SELECT 
    Q.[SQSQueue],
    Q.[SQSMessageID],
    D.[ReceiverID],
    Q.[DLOrder],
    D.[DetectionDate],
    D.[DetectionMS],
    D.[TagID],
    M.[TxAmplitude],
    M.[TxOffset],
    M.[TxNBW],
    M.[TxChkSum]
  FROM         [StQueue] as Q 
    INNER JOIN [StDetection] as D ON Q.eID=D.eID
    INNER JOIN [StDetMeta] as M ON Q.eID=D.eID
WITH VIEW_METADATA
```

I want an underlying autoincrement primary key (eID) to tie the 3 underlying tables together.  In other words, this is the StQueue DDL

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StQueue](
    [eID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SQSQueue] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [SQSMessageID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DLOrder] [int] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [eID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The `Q`,`M`,`D` aliased tables all have `eID`, but I'm willing to remove the `IDENTITY(1,1)` part of the definition (on all except one), as I don't think it's wise to trust that three separate tables will remain synchronous with respect to the value of eID for the next insert.

To avoid this issue, should I do a `SET @ID = COALESCE(IDENT_CURRENT('StQueue'),0)+1`
or

```
SET @ID = SELECT MAX(eID) FROM StQueue
SET @ID = COALESCE(ID,0)+1
```

And then do

```
INSERT INTO StQueue ([SQSQueue], [SQSMessageID],[DLOrder])
  VALUES (SQSQueue, SQSMessageID, DLOrder) From Inserted
INSERT INTO StDetection (eID, ReceiverID, DetectionDate, DetectionMS, TagID)
  VALUES (@ID, ReceiverID, DetectionDate, DetectionMS, TagID) FROM Inserted
INSERT INTO StDetMeta (eID, [TxAmplitude], [TxOffset], [TxNBW], [TxChkSum])
  VALUES (@ID, [TxAmplitude], [TxOffset], [TxNBW], [TxChkSum]) FROM Inserted
```

[Microsoft warns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> Be cautious about using IDENT_CURRENT to predict the next generated
>   identity value. The actual generated value may be different from
>   IDENT_CURRENT plus IDENT_INCR because of insertions performed by other
>   sessions.

I assume this warning applies equally to the `MAX`-based method. Should I `INSERT...WITH TABLOCK` on the underlying tables to avoid that issue? Or would the multi-session/thread issue still be a problem. The problem might still exist because the computation for the next ID number happens before attempting to grab a lock, discovering it's already locked, and spinning wheels until the existing lock is released, the value would be stale any time a lock is encountered or a race exists where two threads are trying to grab the attention of the table (establish a lock) at the same time?  Is there a way I can request a lock for all three tables at once? Would this be wise to do before grabbing `IDENT_CURRENT('StQueue')`?

Will this whole process be slower than `BULK INSERT`ing and then `SELECT eID,x,y,z` from a single master table into the 3 "child" tables? Would iterating through a `CURSOR` be worse?

Comment: after the first Insert into...from `Inserted`, will `Inserted` change values to reflect the sub-table insert rather than the blocked view insert?

Comment: No, definitely don't use `IDENT_CURRENT` ([read more here](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/t-sql-queries/ident-current)). Too bad you're on such an ancient version of SQL Server; in 2012 you could use a single sequence. As for "will x be slower" or "will y be worse" - who knows? You can test with your hardware, schema, data, and usage patterns. We can't.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up abandoning the `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger method initially asked about, as syncing the unique ID across the several tables otherwise was proving problematic.

My current solution, involving the `MERGE` syntax, which as @AaronBertrand blogged about [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/), may be bug-ridden.  For example, it may be subject to unexpected sessions of deadlock down the line. But the following works for now:P

```
CREATE TABLE TxStaging (
    [eID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SQueue] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [SMessageID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [RecID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DLOrder] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DetectionDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [DetectionUS] [decimal](7, 6) NOT NULL,
    [TagID] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [TxAmplitude] [int] NULL,
    [TxOffset] [int] NULL,
    [TxNBW] [int] NULL,
    [TxChkSum] [varchar](25) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [eID] ASC )
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,
      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StQueue](
    [eID] [bigint] /*IDENTITY(1,1)*/ NOT NULL,
    [SQueue] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [SMessageID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DLOrder] [int] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [eID] ASC )
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF,
      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StDets](
    [eID] [bigint] /*IDENTITY(1,1)*/ NOT NULL,
    [RecID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DetectionDate] [datetime2] NOT NULL, --(7)?
--  [DetectionUS] [decimal](7, 6) NULL,
    [TagID] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [eID] ASC )
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StDetMeta](
    [eID] [bigint] /*IDENTITY(1,1)*/ NOT NULL,
    [TxAmplitude] [int] NULL,
    [TxOffset] [int] NULL,
    [TxNBW] [int] NULL,
    [TxChkSum] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [NeworDup] int NULL, --unevaluated = NULL; New = 0; Duplicated_in_this_staging_table = 1; Duplicated_in_main_table = 2
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [eID] ASC )
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE VIEW InsertView as 
SELECT 
    [SQueue],
    [SMessageID],
    [RecID],
    [DLOrder],
    [DetectionDate],
    [DetectionUS],
    [TagID],
    [TxAmplitude],
    [TxOffset],
    [TxNBW],
    [TxChkSum]
FROM TxStaging
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_PropegateSubTables]  --CREATE or ALTER
AS BEGIN
    MERGE INTO realtimetest.dbo.StQueue WITH (HOLDLOCK) as T
        USING realtimetest.dbo.TxStaging as S on T.eID=S.eID
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET T.SQueue=S.SQueue, T.[SMessageID]=S.[SMessageID], T.[DLOrder]=S.[DLOrder]
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
            INSERT (eID, [SQueue], [SMessageID], [DLOrder])
            VALUES (S.eID, S.[SQueue], S.[SMessageID], S.[DLOrder]);
    MERGE INTO realtimetest.dbo.StDets WITH (HOLDLOCK) as T
        USING realtimetest.dbo.TxStaging as S on T.eID=S.eID
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET T.RecID=S.RecID, T.DetectionDate=DATEADD(mcs,CAST(S.DetectionUS*1000000.0 as INT),S.DetectionDate), T.TagID=S.TagID
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
            INSERT (eID, RecID, DetectionDate, TagID)
            VALUES (S.eID, S.RecID, DATEADD(mcs,CAST(S.DetectionUS*1000000.0 as INT),S.DetectionDate), S.TagID);
    MERGE INTO realtimetest.dbo.StDetMeta WITH (HOLDLOCK) as T
        USING realtimetest.dbo.TxStaging as S on T.eID=S.eID
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET T.[TxAmplitude]=S.[TxAmplitude], T.[TxOffset]=S.[TxOffset], T.[TxNBW]=S.[TxNBW], T.[TxChkSum]=S.[TxChkSum]
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
            INSERT (eID, [TxAmplitude], [TxOffset], [TxNBW], [TxChkSum])
            VALUES (S.eID, S.[TxAmplitude], S.[TxOffset], S.[TxNBW], [TxChkSum]);
END
GO
```

Python code to fill TxStaging and then the child tables (has some other `Try:` type logic not included here)

```py
tname = 'InsertView'
fname = 'S:/path/to/In.csv'
fieldSep = ','
linestart = 1
ename = 'S:/path/to/In.err'
sqlconn.execute_non_query("BULK INSERT {} FROM '{}' WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = '{}', ROWTERMINATOR = '{}', MAXERRORS = 1024, FIRSTROW = {}, KEEPNULLS, ERRORFILE = '{}', TABLOCK )".format(tname, fname, fieldSep, chr(10), linestart, ename))
procObj = sqlconn.init_procedure('usp_PropegateSubTables')
procObj.execute()
qstring = "DELETE FROM {}".format(tname) #TO DO: should check for presence of error file before going ahead and deleting this table.
    # clear table/view after propagated, but leave counter valid. Don't use TRUNCATE for this reason
    # TRUNCATE could be used if proceeded by a "check max eID" and then a `DBCC checkident(tname, RESEED, @maxeID)`
sqlconn.execute_non_query(qstring)
```